# Purpose of NServiceBus Headers?

Tags: c#, messaging, nservicebus

I see a description of how to access headers [here](http://www.nservicebus.com/faq/TechnicalMessageInformation.aspx%20/), but can't seem to find any examples of where they are useful.  Some tutorials include code that access the headers, but without any explanation of why.  Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be the case that you need to send some information with the message that is not directly related to the body itself.  This is a similar concept to HTTP headers.  An example of this would be that when a message is forwarded to the error queue, there is some information sent along with it to help you understand what went wrong(including the exception).

Comment: A common use case involves including security information like a user ID in the header which will be checked on the receiving side by a separate handler. Authentication, in short.

Comment: Additional information: In case of errors for example the exception will also be put into the header. This helps to analyze what the root cause was. Very helpful